# Layout centered on one node

Tags: cytoscape.js

Is there a way to require that a layout doesn't change the position of one "root" node while considering it during the algorithm ? Or equivalently, is there a way to always center the camera to this node/keep the camera at the same relative position to this node ?

A bit of context. I am working on an iteratively built graph. Each time parts are added to the graph, the layout is completed. The graph may grow too big to be printed on a screen, and alternatives to the `fit` options are welcome. What is important though, is that the user is able to follow the node he selected. The best would be that this node doesn't move.

Comment: You can center and fit the graph to specific nodes with cy.fit(node) and cy.center(node). That should be enough for your problem, right?

Comment: Both options seems to works for the initial position of the nodes. When the animation ends, the viewport is no longer fitted or center around the chose node. Ideally, the node should not have his screen position changed during the layout animation.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an outline of the general approach.  It can be applied with whatever strategy you like re. zoom and pan.  The main thing is that you need to know the start and end positions of each node.  So you run the layout in a batch, creating a visual nop, and then run a preset layout with the desired zoom and pan.

```js
const clone = obj => Object.assign({}, obj);
const savePos1 = n => n.scratch('_layoutPos1', clone(n.position()));
const savePos2 = n => n.scratch('_layoutPos2', clone(n.position()));
const restorePos1 = n => n.position(n.scratch('_layoutPos1'));
const getPos2 = n => n.scratch('_layoutPos2');

cy.startBatch();

const nodes = cy.nodes();
const layout = cy.layout(myLayoutOptions); // n.b. animate:false
const layoutstop = layout.promiseOn('layoutstop');

nodes.forEach(savePos1); 

layout.run();

await layoutstop;

nodes.forEach(savePos2);

nodes.forEach(restorePos1);

cy.endBatch();

cy.layout({
  name: 'preset',
  animate: true,
  positions: getPos2,

  // specify zoom and pan as desired
  zoom,
  pan
}).run();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With this I can freely choose the zoom and pan I want. But what I wan is that the root node stays at the same position at the screen during the animation, i.e. I want the animation of the pan to be the same as the animation of the root node.

Comment: I've tried to move the pan exactly as the node by computing the difference between positions and adding it to the current pan. It sometimes works. But sometimes the node is moving or the result is just erratic.

Comment: You have to compute the zoom and pan together.  They are dependent.